# c# Datetime of tomorrow

Tags: c#

I am building a helper method that is passed tomorrow's date via a stored procedure call.  The time will be set to `00:00:00.000`, which will convert to `12:00:00am`. Is there another class I need to use?

```cs
public static DateTime GetTomorrow(DateTime incomingDate)
{
    return incomingDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.Date` variable of `DateTime` class, it will return only the date and drop the time from the `incomingDate` variable.

```
    public static DateTime GetTomorrow(DateTime incomingDate)
    {
        return incomingDate.AddDays(1).Date;
    }
```

**Update**

Example of how this works,

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff"));
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Date);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff"));
```

**Output**

```
1/10/2020 1:08:45 PM
01/10/2020 13:08:45.482
1/10/2020 12:00:00 AM
01/10/2020 0:00:00.000
```

Please see [C# Formatting DateTime](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: @jaward for this to work in my query I need it to return 00:00:00.000 for the time

Comment: @Jefferson See my update. What you are talking about is formatting of the date.. not how its represented.